# Collapsing SQL rows into one row based on match of sequential row pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence, data-cleaning, data-processing

I'm working on a project that involves combining a series of actions into sequences. The specific programming question is that I want to figure out how to use SQL (preferably mySQL) to combine multiple rows in a table when these rows match a certain sequence. One caveat is that the table is grouped by two other columns (who did it and what day they did it).

For this example, we are working with a list of actions for people's morning routines. There are two sequences of actions that we want to combine our action list into: wakeup/snoozed alarm and started day. A wakeup/snoozed alarm sequence is a (wakeup row) -> (snooze alarm) row. A started day sequence is a (wakeup row) -> (ate breakfast row) -> (brushed teeth row).

Our raw actions table looks like this: [image: A series of actions for different participants on a different day]

Our desired output looks like this:
[image: A similar action table who's rows matching a certain sequence have been collapsed into one 'sequence' row.]

So far, I've looked into window functions and iteration using mySQL, but both of those don't seem to scale to the fact that I have multiple sequences to match on.

I feel like this might not be possible in SQL, but I thought that I'd post this here in case someone else would know how to tackle this data processing question. The end goal is to have these results stored in a view so whenever we query the actions table in the future, it queries the "processed" actions (ie actions after they've been grouped into sequences).

Comment: Your logic appears to require ordering of the actions.  However, your data has no column that specifies the ordering, so your question doesn't make sense on this data.

Comment: Great point- there is also an autoincremented id for each action (to provide sequence). Changing pictures to match now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `lead()` and then some filtering logic.  First, assign the new actions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when (actionid, next_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'snoozedAlarm')
             then 'wokeup and snoozed'
             when (actionid, next_actionid, next2_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'ateBreakfast', 'brushedTeeth')
             then 'started day'
             else actionid
         end) as action,
from (select t.*,
             lead(actionId, 1) over (partition by person, day order by id) as next_actionid,
             lead(actionId, 2) over (partition by person, day order by id) as next2_actionid
      from t
     ) t;
```

Next, use this information for filtering:

```
with newactions as (
      select t.*,
             (case when (actionid, next_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'snoozedAlarm')
                   then 'wokeup and snoozed'
                   when (actionid, next_actionid, next2_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'ateBreakfast', 'brushedTeeth')
                   then 'started day'
                   else actionid
               end) as action,
             (case when (actionid, next_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'snoozedAlarm')
                   then 2
                   when (actionid, next_actionid, next2_actionid) = ('wokeUp', 'ateBreakfast', 'brushedTeeth')
                   then 1
                   else 0
               end) as duration
      from (select t.*,
                   lead(actionId, 1) over (partition by person, day order by id) as next_actionid,
                   lead(actionId, 2) over (partition by person, day order by id) as next2_actionid
            from t
           ) t
      )
    select na.*
    from (select na.*,
                 lag(duration) over (partition by person order by id) as prev_duration,
                 lag(duration) over (partition by person order by id) as prev2_duration
          from newactions na
         ) na
    where not (prev_duration >= 1 or
               prev2_duration >= 2
              )
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution.
I was having some performance problems (took ~13 seconds to run on 56k rows), but after I ended up adding an index on person and day it sped up to 4 seconds!